# td background-color does not work with stylesheet in JTextPane

Tags: java, html, css, stylesheet, jtextpane

I am going my first steps with `html` `stylesheets`.

I have this style section:

```
td.pel { 
  background-color:red;align:center;
  width:100% 
}
td.d1 { 
  background-color:#D3D3D3; text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
td.d2 { 
  background-color:#BDBDBD;
  text-align:center; 
  vertical-align:middle;
}
table.pet {
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;font-weight:bold;color:white;
}
```

`pel` and `pet` are displayed correctly.
`d1` and `d2` shows the column values in center mode and with the correct vertical alignment but not with the `background-color` that I have defined.

This is the html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='d1'>
            MAY
            <br />
            AB
        </td>
        <td class='d2'>
            MDHR
            <br />
            AN
        </td>
        <td class='d1'>
            MDHR
            <br />
            AB
        </td>
        <td class='d2'>
            MHSB
            <br />
            AN
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='pel'>
            b1i
        </td>
        <td class='pel'>
            33mk
        </td>
        <td class='pel'>
            12dsd
        </td>
        <td class='pel'>
            4sa
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="pet">
    <tr>
        <td>FEED</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This html is added to a JTextPane to display the result in a JFrame:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        textPane.setEditable(false);
        textPane.setText(lHtml);
```

Do you see the problem?

Comment: Can we see the html ?

Comment: You've posted two different sets of styling -- where are these styles being declared? -- i.e. in what order?

Comment: Yes, it's a littlebit confusing. Do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/5fceg3jc/

Comment: Where does `.ds100_AB` comes from ?

Comment: sorry my foult. I copied it from another version. now it should be correct.

Comment: It is working : http://jsfiddle.net/az1sbayr/

Comment: Go to inspect mod with your browser and see if there is any rule that overrides this CSS

Comment: No way to see it in action ? There has to be some other CSS that overrides yours.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642725/changing-the-background-color-of-a-paragraph-in-jtextpane-java-swing ??